# Can't Connect To a user whose name contains a space Character

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a user in Oracle whose name is: Human Resources

in-browser i can connect to it just fine.

However, in SQL command Line, i can't.. there's a problem with the space character

[image]

I can connect to system, and other users, I'm quite sure the problem is in the space character.

**Additional Details :**

Things i've already tried:

"Human Resources"

'Human Resources'

[Human Resources]

Also tried {}, (), **

Comment: Enclose username in double quotation marks. And from now on, try to create users, name of which made up of a single word, not a phrase.

Comment: I've already tried that!! sorry i forgot to mention that, I'll edit my question

Comment: If, as you're saying, there really is a user named `Human Resources` in your system, then that means that that user has been created using double quotation marks(quoted identifier). Enclosing identifier in double quotation marks allows you to use space, as well as any other character none-quoted identifier cannot have, making it case-sensitive as well. `Things i've already tried` SQL*PLUS would not raise `invalid option` error if you enclosed that user name in double quotation marks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'in-browser'? It might be helpful to include the output of `select username from all_users where lower(username) like '%human%'`, to verify they exist and that you have the case of the name right. It's possible the 'browser' is changing the value to uppercase prior to using it to connect, for example, which might not be obvious. (But without knowing quite what you mean, I'd wonder if that's an application username rather than an Oracle account, and the 'browser' is an application front-end rather than part of Oracle itself...)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
SQL> connect
Enter user-name: "Human Resources"@mydb
Enter password: 
Connected.
```